# Conversion Specs

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

What do you put in for the URL Object ID in conversion specs if wanting to use: {'action.type':'link_click', 'post.object':'URL_OBJECT_ID'}

In the example it says: [{"action.type":"like", "page":[133445987]}]

But I do not know where they are getting the number after page or what I would put in if I am directing people to my website. I would like to track when people click on the link and go to the website.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to select with the action spec?

Answer (score 0):

I think you put the pageID in that field- that being said I am trying to do something similiar with following code:

[{"action.type":["link_click"],"post":[xxxx1419],"post.wall":[xxxxx0152]}]
and the ad works, but it doesnt show very often (ie i ahve it set to a $10 daily budget but it only spends 1-2 per day.